# Why is Rails warning me about an SQL snippet which doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to get an app from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.

One particular point in my code is spitting out this warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s)
(one of: users, one.example) that are referenced in a string SQL
snippet. For example: 

    Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")

Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and
knows to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading
comments in a separate query. However, doing this without writing
a full-blown SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want
to write an SQL parser, we are removing this functionality. From
now on, you must explicitly tell Active Record when you are
referencing a table from a string:

    Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")
        .references(:comments)

If you don't rely on implicit join references you can disable the
feature entirely by setting
`config.active_record.disable_implicit_join_references = true`.
(called from authenticate_common at
/path/to/project/app/models/user.rb:72)
```

But the line in question doesn't even contain SQL:

```
def self.authenticate_common(login, password)
  return nil if login.blank? || password.blank?
  # this line outputs the warning:
  user = User.includes(INCLUDES_FOR_AUTH).where(:login => login).first
  # and so does this line
  user ||= User.includes(INCLUDES_FOR_AUTH).where(:email => login).first
  return nil unless user && user.authenticated?(password)
  user
end
```

Not only is the condition here not using SQL, but it isn't even referencing any related models, so the suggested fix cannot be performed. Additionally, there are no scopes in the `User` class which could be adding any default conditions.

The value of `INCLUDES_FOR_AUTH` is:

```
INCLUDES_FOR_AUTH = [{ :roles => [ :permissions ]}]
```

The `Role` and `Permission` classes also lack any SQL snippets, though, so it can't be them.

My only remaining thought is that maybe Rails is generating the SQL snippet and then tripping itself up on its own checks... is that what's going on? :/

The investigation so far:

- After setting the includes to `[]`, the warning still appears.
- After removing all `order` calls from scopes throughout all model classes, the warning still appears.
- If I scatter calls to `references(:user)` throughout the code, it does clear the warning. I'm guessing that this is just masking the problem, because the problem at hand is that I'm not really sure why I have to call `references` in the first place, and if I do have to call it, I would like to do so next to the piece of code which causes it to be required, not all over the place.
- The queries it's ultimately running for these don't make a lot of sense to me because they don't seem to return the actual record:

  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."login" = 'someone@somewhere.com' LIMIT 1
  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'someone@somewhere.com' LIMIT 1

  From the queries, it seems like the where clause is the only one where the data I'm providing is even used, but the SQL there was definitely created by Rails itself.

Comment: What SQL is ultimately executed? Do you have any default scopes in the User, Role, or Permission model?

Comment: The line which outputs the warning is ActiveRecord, which is compiled to SQL. And it references the "User" class. Maybe you should add `.references(:user)` to the active record query and see if that stops the warning.

Comment: references(:user) does clear the warning, but it isn't clear why I need this, because as far as I know, most of the other where() calls throughout the application aren't generating this warning. (A few others are, though.) As far as default scopes, a lot of the model classes have `->{ order('name') }` as the default scope. Obviously a lot of this stuff would generate SQL, but the Rails devs' snarky message about not wanting to write an SQL parser seems incorrect as I'm not the one creating the SQL.

Comment: As far as what SQL it's actually executing... I can't tell. It used to come out on the console but it seems like it's gone now. I wish they would include that in the error message actually, it would really help with figuring out where they have screwed up. :/

Comment: Finally dug the SQL out of a log, but it's not very enlightening. It at least shows that no ordering and other stuff is going on. It's just a basic query with a single WHERE clause which is clearly constructed by Rails from the parameters I have passed in.